# Bootstrap 4 grid layout didn't work as expected

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

According to Bootstrap4 document, we have classes `col-*-num` and `offset-*-num` for designing page layout. In the following code div columns from `sm` to up are the same and only `extra small` view has different columns. So as bootstrap3 I handle that using `col-sm-*` for `small` to up views and `col-xs-*` for `extra small` views. In `small` and up views everything is as desired But surprisingly, in `extra-small` view every `div` occupy a row ! I think I got something wrong in bootstrap4 concepts, What's wrong?

HTML

```
<body>
        <div id="top-ribbon" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div id="logo" class="col-xs-2 offset-xs-1 col-sm-2 offset-sm-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center color-white">Hello
                </div>
                <div id="socials" class="col-xs-3 offset-xs-2 col-sm-2 offset-sm-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-around color-white">
                        0256666666<i class="fa fa-phone color-white"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </body>
```

Css

```
#top-ribbon{
    background-color: rgb(168, 8, 133);
}
#socials i{
    font-size: 20px;
}

#socials, #logo{
    border: 1px solid;
}
.color-white{
    color: white;
}
#top-ribbon1{
    background-color: rgb(168, 8, 133);
}
#socials1 i{
    font-size: 20px;
}

#socials1, #logo1{
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtwmyowc/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grid in bootstrap4 alpha-6 intresting behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462902/grid-in-bootstrap4-alpha-6-intresting-behaviour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since v4.0.0-alpha.6, the `-xs` infix has been dropped. From the release [blog:](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2017/01/06/bootstrap-4-alpha-6/)

> First, we’ve dropped the `-xs` infix from our lowest (extra small) breakpoint. xs isn’t a responsive breakpoint quite like sm, md, lg, and xl because it doesn’t start applying styles at a min-width and up. It simply applies to everything as there’s no bounding @media query

So in your case: `col-xs-2 offset-xs-1` becomes `col-2 offset-1` and `col-xs-3 offset-xs-2` becomes `col-3 offset-2`

Comment: Reading bootstrap4 document, I understood that `col-*` classes are for the situations all views follow the same setting. But after reading your answer I review Bootstrap4 grid document and I should say you're right. But I think it's important Bootstrap4 document announce that more explicitly!